# Remove functionality from ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I have a controller which is used to save data in database. The controller looks like below:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EmployeeFormViewModel viewModel)
{
    var _employee = new Employee
    {
        Employee = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
        DateTime = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} {1}", viewModel.Date, viewModel.Time))
    };

    _context.Employees.Add(_employee);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

I want to remove this line of code

```
DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} {1}", viewModel.Date, viewModel.Time))
```

and make this calculations somewhere else in order to keep the controller clean.
Which is the best way to archive this?

Comment: Have you considered moving that code into the Employee's constructor and just saying `var_employee = new Employee(User.Identity.GetUserId, viewModel.Date, viewModel.Time)` and parsing it there?

Comment: Create a data mapper class that maps the view model data to an entity instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the data given I see that you have used a ViewModel called `EmployeeFormViewModel`  to saperate the logic from the model.  I would guess that your ViewModel looks something like below:

```
public class EmployeeFormViewModel
    {
        public string Venue { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, in order to make the changes in controller, i would suggest you make it look like below:

```
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(EmployeeFormViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var _employee = new Employee
            {
                Employee = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                DateTime = viewModel.DateTime
            };

            _context.Employees.Add(_employee);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

and after that go to your ViewModel and add the new property that you added in the Controller (`DateTime`).  Now your ViewModel should look something like below:

```
public class EmployeeormViewModel
    {
        public string Venue { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} {1}", Date, Time));
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To offer a different perspective, I'd suggest you could put it in an extension method.  The *concept* of combining date and time strings doesn't really feel like it should belong to your domain model, it feels like a generic thing that you might want to use across your application (or even in other applications).  I would do this...

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
  public static DateTime ParseToDateTime(this string date, string time = null)
  {
     return string.IsNullOrEmpty(withTime) ? DateTime.Parse(date) : DateTime.Parse($"{date} {time}");
  }
}
```

And in the controller...

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EmployeeFormViewModel viewModel)
{
    var _employee = new Employee
    {
        Employee = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
        DateTime = viewModel.Date.ParseToDateTime(viewModel.Time)
    };
```

EDIT: Additionally...to incorporate [etr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464050/etr)'s answer, which is also a good approach, you could combine the two...

```
public class EmployeeormViewModel
    {
        public string Venue { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime
        {
            get
            {
                return Date.ParseToDateTime(Time);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rich domain is the way.

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee(int id, object date, object time)
    {
        Id = id;
        DateTime = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} {1}", date, time))
    }

    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime DateTime  { get; protected set; }
}
```

And them:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EmployeeFormViewModel viewModel)
{
    _context.Employees.Add(new Employee(User.Identity.GetUserId(), viewModel.Date, viewModel.Time));
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: `object` for date and time? What is this, .NET 1.0?

Comment: I didn't know what types you used in viewModel.Date and viewModel.Time, so I used object.

Answer (score 0):

I like strong type binding and a Post method as follows:

```
public ActionResult Create(EmployeeFormViewModel viewModel)
{

    viewModel.Post(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    _context.Employees.Add(_employee);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

The view model looking like this:

```
public class EmployeeFormViewModel
{
     Employee Employee { get; set; }
     DateTime Date { get; set; }
     DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public void Post(int empid)
    {
        Employee= new Employee
        {
            EmployeeID = empid,
            DateTime = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} {1}", Date, Time))
        };
        return;

    }
}
```

This is all possible because of the nice MVC Binding engine which generates the EmployeeFormViewModel based on query strings, prior to calling the action method.

I put a "Post" method in all of my ViewModels and let MVC do the work.